# How to pre-populate SharePoint:FormField in SharePoint 2013 without JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need to pre-populate a `SharePoint:FormField` in Visual Studio without the use of JavaScript. I have tried using the query string to no luck. Here is the form field in question:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="FormField1" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Name1" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Name1')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the default value for that field? Otherwise, you may have to use javascript to fill the field value.